# How to set color of status bar showing carrier, time, and battery on top

Tags: ios, swift

I have a ViewController which is the 1st to be loaded and I don't use the NavigationController to navigate to the next VC. I use Segue.

I have a background image which covers the entire screen for this 1st VC.
It covers the status bar for Carrier/Time/Battery and the color turn black. User will not able to see the battery life.

There is no view controller-based status bar property in my project info.plist file(In setting it to NO)

What do I need to do to set the color white or another color to make the staus bar visible?

```
override func viewWillAppear() {    
    super.viewWillAppear()
    var nav = self.navigationController?.navigationBar
    nav?.barStyle = UIBarStyle.Black
    nav?.tintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    nav?.titleTextAttributes = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.orangeColor()]
}
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can `override` the `preferredStatusBarStyle` to `.lightContent`

```
override var preferredStatusBarStyle: UIStatusBarStyle {
    return .lightContent
}
```

Comment: It works. it works.  Just a question. Is this LightContent always white color? How to make it app wide for all the ViewControllers in the project?

Comment: I got it. I like it to be a per view controller setting.

Comment: It works. @ElgsQianChen put the code inside your ViewController class.

Comment: Unfortunately doesn't work if your navbar is transparent :(

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
- (BOOL)prefersStatusBarHidden {
    return NO;
}
```